# Presentar datos de un arreglo en un Qlabel

Tags: python

introducir el código aquíSoy nuevo en Python y deseo saber si existe la forma de crear un Qlabel a partir de la información que tengo en un arreglo, el Qlabel se creara automáticamente, mostrando la información, estoy utilizando PyQt5

#Tengo esta función que se ejecutara cuando de clic en un botón y agregara el contenido que se encuentra en el arreglo

```
def _addInfoToMainScreen(self):

    self.infoPiscinas["Nombre"] = "Piscina Santa"
    self.infoPiscinas["Area Piscina"] = 320
    self.infoPiscinas["Cantidad de alimentadores"] = 4
    self.arr_Piscinas.append(self.infoPiscinas)
```

Tengo que crear un Qlabel con los datos del arreglo que por el momento es estático, como podría crear el Qlabel, estoy investigando y buscando varias alternativas, de antemano les agradezco muchísimo.

Comment: has buscado información? que has investigado?

Comment: Si, se puede, pero para poder responder tienes que aportar de tu parte. Crea una pequeña aplicación, con un sólo Qlabel por contenido, para comenzar a trabajar desde ahí.

Comment: Siempre agrega un poco de codigo en el que estes trabajando